# Populating form_dropdown with a foreach (Codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I have the following select box:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('select-something',$options); ?>
```

For options I am trying to display results from a query I did by appending them to the $options array. E.g.

```
$options = array(); //which should be like 'option1'=>'foo',
foreach($queryExample->result() as $example){
    $options[$example->id] = $example->name;
}
```

It is giving me the error for the form_dropdown:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array...
```

Comment: Travis, shure please move it if needed.

Comment: Please post the code where you're setting `$queryExample`.

Comment: What's the full error message, including file name and line number?

Answer (score 0):

`$this->db->result()` returns an object.
Use `$this->db->result_array()` to get your rows as an array, which will make iteration easier.

Comment: Objects can be iterated, this is irrelevant.